# Как сделать плавное изменение ширины блока при наведении на него?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, блок

Необходимо сделать плавное изменение ширины блока при наведении на него.
При наведении мышкой на блок он должен увеличиться до нужного размера. В случае, если убрать курсор мыши раньше, чем блок увеличится до нужного размера, то в этом случае блок не должен останавливаться, а должен закончить изменение своего размера.

Пока курсор мыши наведен на блок, блок должен оставаться в измененном/увеличенном состоянии.

Когда курсор мыши убираешь с блока, то блок должен вернуться в исходное положение, но не сразу, а с задержкой в пару секунд. В случае, если во время уменьшения блока навести курсор мыши на блок, то блок должен сначала вернуться в исходное положение, а после уже увеличиваться.
Вот такая стоит задача. Очень прошу мне помочь.

```
<div class="div1">Block1</div>

div { 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid #000;
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".div1").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).animate({ 
                width: 500
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: "200px"
                }, 
                {duration:300, queue: false} 
            )
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
 $('#block').hover(
    function(){
  $(this).animate({width:200,height:200});
 },
    function(){      
           $(this).animate({width:100,height:100});
 });
});
```

```css
#block {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

и с задержкой в пару секунд:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#block').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      });
    },

    function() {
      var k= $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        k.animate({
          width: 100,
          height: 100
        });

      }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `jquery.animate()` для анимации и `setTimeout()` для паузы. Но советую вам сначала привести пример вашего кода, за вас его никто писать не будет!